# Minkowski functional on infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, finsler-geometry

In finite-dimensional Finsler geometry, we define the Minkowski functional on tangent spaces, which are finite dimensional vector spaces. The definition of Minkowski functional can be generalized to infinite-dimensional vector spaces that admit inner product at least but I have not found in literature such a generalization. Is there a problem with using this definition in infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: I imagine the problem is the definition of volume (and its derivatives) for linear combinations of convex bodies in infinite dimensions.  Deane Yang or Semyon Alesker will know more about this.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested not in full generality of finsler geometry, mainly for defining the length of curves and perhaps continuity of norms suffices .

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know anything about this. I’ve never thought about the infinite dimensional case, where the challenges and questions  are usually quite different from the finite dimensional case. Maybe some of our friends in Banach space theory would know something about this?

Comment: Sorry, I think i mixed up "mixed volumes" with "Minkowski functional" (i.e. the possibly asymmetric norm associated to a convex body containing the origin in its interior). What is it exactly you want? Do you have closed bounded convex sets which contain a nbd of the origin in each tangent space and want to get a Finsler metric from that?

Comment: @alvarezpaiva, I'm always confused by what the "Minkowski functional" is.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at "Pseudodistances and Pseudometrics on Real and Complex Manifolds" by SERGIO VENTURINI

Comment: @DeaneYang, me too. I've seen it used in different contexts, but according to Wikipedia it is basically just the norm or semi-norm associated to a convex set that contains the origin in its interior. That is, the value at $x$ is the infimum of $\lambda$ so that $x$ is in the dilate $\lambda K$.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva,In literature as far as I have seen a  Finsler metric is defined as a minkowski functional on the tangent bundle and it is emphasized that spaces are finite dimensional. I dont understand why, it seems to me that we can define a finsler metric  on infinite dimensional spaces also  as the same way.

Comment: @erz, thanks for the recommendation, it is a very interesting paper.

Comment: The Minkowski functional makes sense for arbitrary locally convex spaces (in fact, this is how you define the seminorms associated to a local basis). Maybe the following is helpful for the definition of a Finsler structure in infinite dimensions: https://books.google.nl/books?id=SOYbCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA65&ots=ycK2w93nXs&dq=SUBRAMANIAM%20slices%20for%20actions&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: There is absolutely no problem in defining infinite-dimensional Finsler manifolds. In every case it is a continuous (and as much more as your structure allows) function defined on the tangent space such that when you restrict it to every tangent space it yields a norm. Check out page 587 in Uhlenbeck's paper for something definite: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214431176

Comment: Note that the interesting part in the hypotheses is that the norms in the tangent spaces are locally equivalent.

Comment: @TobiasDiez, alvarezpaiva, thanks for the recommendation. Something that I am curious about to what extent can we generalize finsler geometry to infinite dimensional manifolds (for example different notion of connections ) . As I see, it is used for infinite dimensional but it is not developed enough yet. It is well known that on manifolds modeled on locally convex spaces  we have weak Riemannian metric and it would be difficult to work with these metric, what about Finsler metrics?